# Using $(array).each to iterate over array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I recently came upon a jQuery construction I hadn't seen before. Here's a simplified version:

```
$([ '1', '2', '3' ]).each( function( index, value ) {
  console.log( "index", index, "value", value );
});
```

This iterates over all the elements of the array `[ '1', '2', '3' ]`. The thing is, I'm used to seeing `$(...)` used with a CSS selector, but I haven't seen it used on a newly declared array, as is being done here. It seems to work, though (tested with Firefox 34 and Chromium 39).

**Q1:** Am I correct in understanding that this is equivalent to

```
var a = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
for ( var i = 0, value; value = a[i]; i++ ) {
  console.log( "index", i, "value", value );
}
```

If not, what are the differences? (apart from the fact that this declares variables `a`, `i` and `value`).

**Q2:** As far as iterating over arrays in jQuery is concerned, I'm more used to `$.each` (not to be confused with `$(selector).each` as used above). Would the above be equivalent to

```
$.each( [ '1', '2', '3' ], function( index, value ){
  console.log( "index", index, "value", value );
});
```

if yes, why are there two such extremely similar constructions in jQuery? Between the two, what is the preferred way to iterate over arrays, or is this just a matter of personal style?

Comment: You *can* do `$([ '1', '2', '3' ]).each`.  This will create a jQuery object that instead of containing DOM elements, will contain strings.  You shouldn't do it that way, though.  If you want to use jQuery, then you should do `$.each( [ '1', '2', '3' ]`.  This is equivalent to doing `var a = [ '1', '2', '3' ]; a.forEach(function(v, i){});`, as it's running a callback (closure) for each element.

Comment: Very clever use of a for loop!

Comment: Very **SLOW** equivalent of a for loop!

Comment: According to the doc, $.each() is generic and $().each() is for jQuery objects

Comment: @DavidBarker In a scenario where there are typically only ever a handful of items to loop over the performance difference won't matter very much. The `.each()` approach has its merits, primarily because it enables a functional style of programming.

Comment: The preferred way to iterate over plain arrays in jQuery has been, and still is `$.each(arr)`. Many people still use `$(arr).each`, which works, but is incorrect. Also, doing `$.each( $('.elems') )` is incorrect as well.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Comment: It should be noted that using jQuery on plain arrays is not really neccessary at all, as all modern browsers support the native `forEach`

Comment: `$.fn.each()` calls internally `$.each()` so there is no difference between both except the correct intend to use one or the other

Comment: @A.Wolff - good point, all `$(arr).each(...` does internally is `jQuery.each(this, callback, args);` so it's exactly the same really

Comment: @A.Wolff Not in the iteration, but in the useless and superfluous jQuery object creation.

Comment: @Tomalak Ya, completly superfluous regarding array or plain object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1.** Yes.

**Q2.** jQuery accepts arrays (and array-like objects) and turns them into jQuery objects.

You can see that easily by issuing, on the browser console:

```
console.dir($([ '1', '2', '3' ]))
> VM199:2 e.fn.e.init[3]
```

That's a jQuery object that call returns. They can be iterated over with `.each()`. This facility is meant to enable you to do this (contrived example):

```
$(document.getElementsByTagName("A")).each(func);
```

Doing so with a plain array of strings works, and will likely continue to work in the future, however I still see that as a mis-use of the API and would recommend the proper approach:

```
$.each(['1', '2', '3' ], func);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Q1**: As other said, yes.

**Q2**: Ill start by saying *not because you can that you should*.

It is right that you can use `$([ '1', '2', '3' ]).each()` and it will work, but it isn't efficient.

Both are not the same (they are similar though). As said in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array.

Which mean that if you use `$([ '1', '2', '3' ]).each()` you are creating a jQuery object which is not needed. It is way faster, performance wise, the property `each` of the jQuery object then calling the function passing an array than calling a function creating a jQuery object of an array and then access to its prototype `.each()`.